# Replace the legacy Stack with what from Java Collections?

Tags: java, collections, stack

This is kind of a Java trivia question perhaps.

I have used the [Stack](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html) implementation many times.

I have read that this is considered a legacy class and due to the fact that it subclasses `Vector` makes its performance bad in single threaded applications.

My question is, what is the best alternative among the Java Collection classes?

Is there another `Stack` class available (by a different name perhaps) that is the one to choose?

I mean, ok implementing a stack arround another existing data structure is easy, but I would expect there is an existing `Stack` to use.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you read a more current Javadoc (1.6 or 1.7 for example) rather than the old 1.4.2 docs, you'll find:

> A more complete and consistent set of LIFO stack operations is provided by the Deque interface and its implementations, which should be used in preference to this class

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html

Comment: Well, it is. It just happens to be faster than a `Stack` :)

Answer (score 6):

In Java7, you can use

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#asLifoQueue(java.util.Deque)

to get a Stack-like object. add() works like push() and remove() works like pop(), etc. I'm answering here long after the question was asked because this seems to be the new 'right' answer for this.

Answer (score 3):

[LinkedList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) implements `push` and `pop` methods. See also other [Deque](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html) implementations.

Commons Collections implements an [ArrayStack](http://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/ArrayStack.html) class.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`LinkedList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) which implements the `Deque` interface and allows pushing and popping.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a Deque to add and remove things from the same end.

Comment: Isn't that a Double Ended Queue?I.e. a Queue and not a Stack?

Comment: @user384706 What's the meaningful difference between a stack and a queue other than a queue provides more access points?

Comment: Stack is a LIFO.Queue is a FIFO.The retrieval is different

Comment: @user384706 *Meaningful* difference: you can use a double-ended queue as a stack.

Comment: @Dave:Sorry I miss your point here.You asked me what is the meaningful difference of a stack and a queue.Insn't the retrieval order a meaningful difference.The fact that both can be implementated over the same datastructure e.g. an array, does not make them equivalent.Unless your are trying to tell me something else.Sorry I lost you

Comment: A Deque is a *double ended* queue.  If you add and remove things from the same end, either the start or from the end you have a Stack.

Answer (score 2):

From the Stack javadoc:

> A more complete and consistent set of LIFO stack operations is
>   provided by the Deque interface and its implementations, which should
>   be used in preference to this class.
>
> **Deque** stack = new **ArrayDeque**();